# What is the best way to create a countdown timer in Cocos2d-x?

Tags: timer, cocos2d-x

I am making a game in cocos2dx but I don't know how to create a countdown timer so that the player only has a certain amount of time to complete the level before time runs out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `schedule` method to call a function after a certain amount of time and update your timer's label accordingly.

Check this out:

1. Create a private `int` member called `countdown` for instance and initialize it with the number of seconds you want to countdown from. Also, declare the timer's `Label` (let's call it `lbl`)
2. in your scene's `init` method, schedule an updater and initialize the label like this

   ```
   this->lbl = Label::createWithTTF(std::to_string(this->countdown), "fonts/Marker Felt.ttf", charSize / 15);    // make sure you #include <string>
   lbl->setPosition(Vec2(0,0));     // set the position to wherever you like
   this->schedule(schedule_selector(MySceneClass::updateTimer), 1.0f);    // calls updateTimer once every second
   ```
3. declare and implement the `updateTimer` to look something like this:

   ```
   void MySceneClass::updateTimer(float dt)    
   {
       if (!countdown)
           return;     // when countdown reaches 0, stop updating to avoid negative values
       lbl->setString(std::to_string(--countdown));
   }
   ```